# dpkg --print-avail PACKAGE fails

Tags: 10.04, apt, dpkg

I just happened to notice that `dpkg --print-avail PACKAGE` (same as `dpkg -p PACKAGE`) is failing on my Ubuntu 10.04.2 server. Should I be concerned?

For example:

```
$ dpkg -p a2ps
Package `a2ps' is not available.
```

But:

```
$ dpkg -l a2ps
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name            Version         Description
+++-===============-===============-==============================================
ii  a2ps            1:4.14-1        GNU a2ps - 'Anything to PostScript' converter
```

Also, `apt-cache show a2ps`, recommended in the dpkg manual for "Users of APT-based frontends" (like me), *does* work.

Based on these bugs, I'm guessing it doesn't matter that `dpkg -p PACKAGE` fails:

- http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=43573
- http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=137128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to be concerned at all. `dpkg` only looks to see if packages are available in `/var/lib/dpkg/available` From the manpage:

```
          -p, --print-avail package-name...
              Display details about package-name, as found in
              /var/lib/dpkg/available. Users of APT-based frontends
              should use apt-cache show package-name instead.
```

Where `apt-cache policy PACKAGE` also checks your apt sources.